# How do I load one page after another with UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiwebview

In my app I have an array of URLs that I would like to be loaded into a single UIWebView sequentially. So each would wait for the previous one to finish loading before firing.

How would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your `UIWebView` set its delegate to be self, and add the following function

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //Load the other request  
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I see this will allow me to load page a, then page b, but what if I then need to load pages c, d, e... etc.?

Comment: Also, I have two separate UIWebViews in my view, how do I know which uiwebview would trigger the didfinishload?

Comment: in webViewDidFinishLoad, check for which url the webview finished by using     [webView.request.URL absoluteString], if this url is a, then load b if its c then load d

Comment: to know which UIWebView is doing the loading, check if webview == yourFirstWebview or webView === yourSecondWebView

Comment: I have managed to get the didfinishload to detect the correct webview, I have also managed to correctly check which url has finished loading using the above method. This all works correctly with NSLogs monitoring where I'm at... However as soon as I add in a function: i.e. requesting a new URL to be loaded the app crashes with no information left for me in the debug window.. Any ideas?